# Linear Mixed Effects: removing residual outliers

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, outliers, residuals, model

I have a question about how to remove residual outliers in linear mixed-effects models (i.e., data points with standardized residuals exceeding 2.5 standard deviation units). Should I remove these outliers after fitting the data to the simplest model (i.e., that including only random effects)? Or should I remove them after fitting the data to the full model (i.e, that including fixed effect, interactions and random effects)?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? They may be the most interesting finding from your study.

Comment: Because I guess that significance of fixed effects may be biased by them.

Comment: Have you considered whether a more robust error distribution - e.g. t-distribution may be better? Then a few outliers are less influential.